# how to achieve spring cloud config server canary

Tags: spring-cloud

Trying to wrap my mind around canary rollout of a config change. All the app instances are using the same profile & label. 
Essentially i want to apply a dynamic change but not to all app instances at once.

Any thoughts ? I want to avoid writing any consumer side logic for this.

Comment: Haven't thought much about it. My first guess would be that a canary cluster would be pointed to a different branch. Put the config in the branch and refresh canary. If it works, merge to master (or whatever is the default for non-canary) and refresh.

Comment: Ok, this is reasonable. I was thinking more in terms of targeting a few select instances (within the running cluster), but this (canary cluster) would work as well. 

Thanx,